# Label with icon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

How do i add icons beside my labels in qGIS?. i have a layer displayed with label

[image]

How do i add icons in their labels to look something like this?

[image]

I try to find it in label options but i cant find it. maybe you have the best solutions there.

Comment: From a cartographic/visualisational point of view this is not desirable. A point indicates that there is something right where the point is - which is not the case here. The label is for the whole area, thus you'd make wrong suggestions placing the point in front of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Japanese langauage characters to do what you want. For example, maru (まる) means circle, and once you write まる using Japanese keyboards it will give some options including this ●.

But I think it will be difficult to handle that, so the other solution is to copy and paste the symbols from this website: [Special Characters and Symbols](https://www.hadamitzky.de/english/lp_special_chars.htm) and add it in the label expression as:

```
'● ' || FieldName
```

[image]

Also you can use Character Map in your system (here I am using Windows) to select the symbol and paste it in the expression.

[image]

Here is the output:

[image]

**EDIT**:

I think what you want is the locations of the towns in Philippines. If I understand you correctly, you want to display the points that represent the towns and display their names. Try to download the the towns from [NaturalEarth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/). You need to download the town places (point shapefile), and use their names as label.

As @[Erik](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/109646/erik) says the circles usually represnt something on the map. Just adding circles beside the name without any specific reason will confuse the reader of your map.

Comment: +1 for Maru!  yay :D

Comment: @Kazuhito-san ありがとうございました。:)